# How to insert values from one table to another with respective fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `tbl_cart` and `tbl_sales`.

My table cart has 2 fields `product_id` and `quantityCart`.

```
//SELECT ALL FROM CART
$insertCustomer = "SELECT * FROM cart;";
$exec = mysqli_query($connection, $insertCustomer);

//ASSIGN EACH ROW TO $cart_array
$cart_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) {
    $cart_array[] = array(
        "product_id" => $row['product_id'], 
        "quantityCart" => $row['quantityCart'], 
    );
}
```

`print_r($cart_array)` shows me these:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 1 [quantityCart] => 20 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 2 [quantityCart] => 20 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 3 [quantityCart] => 20 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [product_id] => 4 [quantityCart] => 20 ) )
```

My `tbl_sales` have these fields `sale_id`(Primary and AI), `product_id`, `product_quantity`.

I want to achieve something like this but using array:

`INSERT INTO sales (product_id, product_quantity) VALUES (1,20)
 INSERT INTO sales (product_id, product_quantity) VALUES (1,20)
 INSERT INTO sales (product_id, product_quantity) VALUES (1,20)
 INSERT INTO sales (product_id, product_quantity) VALUES (1,20)`

Now my question is how do I achieve this using PHP/SQL?

Comment: why not just insert select query, just like gordon's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing all this in one query?  If I understand the intent of the code:

```
INSERT INTO sales(product_id, product_quantity) 
    SELECT product_id, quantityCart
    FROM cart;
```